# JavaScript click event on input autosuggest item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, functional-programming

## I can't bind a click event on the item list, the box keeps disappearing. Any idea why on click of the item-list > div i can't bind a click event on div i need to fetch the text and append in the input placeholder ?

```js
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');
    $(".item-list div").click(function() {
      var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
      var data = $(this).text();
      inputValue.val(data);
    });
  }).blur(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Please add your HTML so we can run it -->
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you also add the html to the question please

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippit. Please edit your post, then edit the snippit and add your HTML so we can better help, and see how the code currently behalves. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the event methods (`.focus()`, `blur()`) directly. Instead use `.on(event)`

Comment: You just added a link to the library, could you add elements that your javascript refers too.

Comment: i have edited the HTML , can you suggest an alternative for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is NOT binding the click event, you are calling the click event.

```
$(".item-list div").click() 
{
  var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
  var data = $(this).text();
  inputValue.val(data);
}
```

It should be

```
$(".item-list div").off('click').click( function () { 
  var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
  var data = $(this).text();
  inputValue.val(data);
});
```

---

Changed click to mousedown and it works because when you click the blur event fires and causes the list to be hidden before the click action is complete.

```js
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');
    $(".item-list div")
      .off('mousedown')
      .on('mousedown', function () { 
        var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
        var data = $(this).text();
        inputValue.val(data);
      });
  }).blur(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Please add your HTML so we can run it -->
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item two</div>
    <div>This is item three</div>
    <div>This is item four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @espacarello, its doesn't seem to work any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `.click()` syntax is wrong, it should be in the form

```
.click(function(){
    //your code here
})
```

I've updated your code

```
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');
    $(".item-list div").click(function(){ 
      var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
      var data = $(this).text();
      inputValue.val(data);
    })
  }).blur(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```